# Generate Distinct List and Sum On Conditional VLookUp

Tags: arrays, excel, sumproduct

[Sample Data Sets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BynI.jpg)

I'm trying to write a formula that can fill in revenue amounts in Table3. What I need is for it first to search through Table1 and return an array with each *unique* ID referenced by the domain.

So for a.com it would return {1,2,3}.

It would then find the revenue value in Table2 that is associated with that ID.

For the array above it would be {100,200,400}.

It would then sum those values to arrive at {700} which would populate cell H3 or [@[Sum of Revenue]] for "a.com".

I've tried using sumproduct and combining it with variations of

`{=INDEX(Table1[ID],MATCH(0,COUNTIF($H$2:H2,Table1[ID])+(Table1[Domains]<>$G$3),0))}`

But I'm having trouble at arriving at the full array and not just the first, second, etc. unique value in the array. I also don't know how to end up with the revenue values in the array instead of just the IDs. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

This is what ended up working:

`{=SUM(SUMIF(Table2[ID],IF(FREQUENCY(IF(Table1[Domain]=[@Domain],Table1[ID]),Table1[ID]),Table1[ID]),Table2[Revenue]))}`